# Express enabling CORs headers still cause errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express, cors

Using the code provided by [http://enable-cors.org/ for express](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html) I've added to my index.js file

```
/*these first five line direct from http://enable-cors.org/.com*/
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});




var PORT = 3333;
app.listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log('listening on port', PORT);
})

request({url: 'http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json', json: true}, function(err, data){
  app.get('/us', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req) //prints correctly
    res.json(data.body);
    });
});
```

*localhost:3333/us* shows the json correctly, but making a request from *localhost:3000* (a port being served by browsersync) fails with the error

> `d3.min.js:1XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3333/us. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Is this no longer the correct way to enable CORS for localhost on express? I've also tried passing the `app.use` method `'*'` and `'/us'` as its first argument but no luck.

Comment: This is an important clue: "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes" please include the code you are using to send this ajax request, because apparently it isn't http or https, meaning it likely has nothing to do with your server.

Comment: @KevinB you are correct. When I added `http` I received `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` but I believe that's because of a CORs chrome extension I had turned on. Removing that has eliminated the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making an Ajax call, you need a fully qualified URL with the protocol in it.  This is not a legal URL:

```
localhost:3333/us
```

It is something you can type in the browser and the browser will automatically add a protocol to it (the browser does all sorts of things to try to make what you type in the URl bar into a legal URL, but that logic does not happen for requests made via Javascript and Ajax).  Instead, change the URL to:

```
http://localhost:3333/us
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend just npm installing "cors" as a dependancy. Once you've done that just require and app.use it before all the routes you want to allow CORS.

```js
// Dependancies
var cors = require('cors');

// Init express app
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

// Routes now allow cors
app.get('/api/endpoint', controllers.endpoint);
```